# How to redirect to another subpage using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have the link

http://www.example.com/mysite/administration/objects

I want to redirect to page

http://www.example.com/mysite/administration/reports

using jquery. But I don't want to write the direct link, only replace `objects` to `reports` I want something like this

```
window.location = './reports;
```

but I get
.../administration/objects/reports

**EDIT**

And what if I pass some id in request

http://www.example.com/mysite/administration/objects/33

I still want to get
http://www.example.com/mysite/administration/reports

If I use replace() I get the wrong url
http://www.example.com/mysite/administration/reports/33

Comment: That should actually work just fine with `./reports`  -  does it do the same thing with out the `./` in front of reports?

Comment: truly said, the first answer to my question helped me. I wanted to accept it, but the author deleted it. `window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname.replace('/objects', '/reports')`

Comment: i would think you'd need `../reports` (`.` = current folder, `..` = parent folder)

Comment: @andrew, thanks, it is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

just do 'reports' if it's in the same folder

```
window.location = 'reports';
```

Comment: I still get .../administration/objects/reports

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not necessary, and `window.location.replace(...)` will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

It is better than using `window.location.href =`, because `replace()` does not put the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use location.href. If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace.`

**For example:**

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```